# PHP div for every 12 images

Tags: php, foreach, flickr

i have this piece of code:

```
<?
include( "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=22352410@N07&lang=en-us&format=php" );
$i = 0;
    foreach($feed['items'] as $item) {
    preg_match("/<img src=\"([^\"]+)\" .*? \/>/", $item['description'], $matches);
    $img_html = $matches[0];
    $img_src = $matches[1];
    $medium_url = ereg_replace("_m", "_s", $img_src);
        echo "$img_html";
    }

?>
```

How I could make that each N number of pictures appear inside of a `<div></div>` 
Example:

```
<div class="container">
<img src="1.jpg" /> 
<img src="2.jpg" /> 
<img src="3.jpg" /> 
<img src="4.jpg" /> 
<img src="5.jpg" /> 
<img src="6.jpg" /> 
<img src="7.jpg" /> 
<img src="8.jpg" /> 
<img src="9.jpg" /> 
<img src="10.jpg" /> 
<img src="11.jpg" /> 
<img src="12.jpg" /> 
</div>
<div class="container">
<img src="13.jpg" /> 
<img src="14.jpg" /> 
<img src="15.jpg" /> 
<img src="16.jpg" /> 
<img src="17.jpg" /> 
<img src="18.jpg" /> 
<img src="19.jpg" /> 
<img src="20.jpg" /> 
<img src="21.jpg" /> 
<img src="22.jpg" /> 
<img src="23.jpg" /> 
<img src="24.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

etc...

Any Ideas??

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: before going any further you must parse the JSON returned from URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the double div: Move the if statement, that checks whether there is a remainder down, below the statement that increments the counter, and it will not create the double div:

```
<?
include( "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=22352410@N07&lang=en-us&format=php" );
$i = 0;
echo "<div class='container'>";
foreach($feed['items'] as $item) 
{
     preg_match("/<img src=\"([^\"]+)\" .*? \/>/", $item['description'], $matches);
     $img_html = $matches[0];
     $img_src = $matches[1];
     $medium_url = ereg_replace("_m", "_s", $img_src);
     echo "$img_html";
     $i++;
     if($i % 12 === 0)
          print "</div><div class='container'>";
}
print "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check with `%12`. In your loop you add a counter `$j`, at each loop you increment `$j`.

When `$j % 12 === 0` then you have to change your div by adding `</div><div class="container">`.

Don't forget about the first and last `<div>` markups.

Answer (score 1):

Should do it!

```
<?
include( "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=22352410@N07&lang=en-us&format=php" );
    $i = 0;
    echo "<div class='container'>";
    foreach($feed['items'] as $item) 
    {
         if($i % 12 === 0)
              print "</div><div class='container'>";
         preg_match("/<img src=\"([^\"]+)\" .*? \/>/", $item['description'], $matches);
         $img_html = $matches[0];
         $img_src = $matches[1];
         $medium_url = ereg_replace("_m", "_s", $img_src);
         echo "$img_html";
         $i++;
    }
    print "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: No, it puts a double div :-) <div class='container'></div><div class='container'><img src=...

Comment: Yeah, change to 'if (!$i%12 && $i)'

Comment: Now i Had only 1 div (and more of 12 images inside :-))

Answer (score 0):

You have an `$i=0` there, but you're not using it. There's no 12-line pagination algorithm either. How about trying some `$i++` somewhere in your loop and thinking about where to insert an `if ($i==12)` or `if ($i%12)` somewhere. Sorry, I don't intend to spoon-feed. This is a basic problem you'll find in textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing foreach, use a simple for loop with counter, and then use MOD on the counter to determine if the current iteration is divisible by N.

MOD:  http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

For Loop:  http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forloop.php

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what others have said

- You should always check the return
  value of `preg_match` before you use
  `$match`.
- `ereg_replace` is deprecated. Use
  `preg_replace` instead. Since you are
  just doing a text replacement, you
  should be using `str_replace`